# Segmentation fault при использовании redisAsyncCommand()

Tags: c, redis

Здравствуйте.
Есть вот такой небольшой кусок кода:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include "hiredis.h"
    #include "async.h"
    #include "adapters/libevent.h"

void onMessage(redisAsyncContext *c, void *reply, void *privdata) {
    redisReply *r = reply;
    if (reply == NULL) return;

    int j;

    if (r->type == REDIS_REPLY_ARRAY) {
        for (j = 0; j < r->elements; j++) {
            printf("%u) %s\n", j, r->element[j]->str);
        }
    }*/
}


int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    struct event_base *base = event_base_new();

    redisAsyncContext *c = redisAsyncConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
    if (c->err) {
        printf("error: %s\n", c->errstr);
        return 1;
    }

    redisLibeventAttach(c, base);
    redisAsyncCommand(c, onMessage, NULL, "SUBSCRIBE messages");
    event_base_dispatch(base);
    return 0;
}
```

Код компилируется и запускается, но при вызове функции redisAsyncCommand() программа выдает Segmentation fault.

Comment: Вам похоже уже ответили https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751252/segmentation-fault-when-using-redisasynccommand

Comment: Да, но делу это не помогло. Проблема в самом вызове функции redisAsyncCommand(). Если функцию закомментировать, то все ок. Если же вызов функции оставить, убрать все содержимое функции onMessage(), то проблема остается.